# How to generate a numbered index for results of SELECT query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database related to a 2 player digital board game. I have created a query that, when given a user id, will return a list of played games records. I want the results to be accompanied by a numbered index, but I am unable to find a way to generate one.

There are 4 tables in my database: users, games, layouts, and users_games. The first 3 tables all have an id column which is the primary key and used as a foreign key in tables which reference it. The users_games table has no primary key.

[image]

Here is my query so far:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (games.id) row_number() over() AS num,
 (SELECT nickname FROM users INNER JOIN users_games ON users.id = users_games.user_id WHERE id != 'some_user_id' AND game_id = games.id ) AS opponent_name,
 (SELECT score FROM users_games WHERE game_id = games.id and user_id != 'some_user_id') as opponent_score, 
 (SELECT score FROM users_games WHERE game_id = games.id and user_id = 'some_user_id') as player_score,
 (SELECT
  CASE
   WHEN (SELECT score FROM users_games WHERE game_id = games.id and user_id = 'some_user_id') > (SELECT score FROM users_games WHERE game_id = games.id and user_id != 'some_user_id') THEN 'Won'
   WHEN (SELECT score FROM users_games WHERE game_id = games.id and user_id != 'some_user_id') > (SELECT score FROM users_games WHERE game_id = games.id and user_id = 'some_user_id') THEN 'Lost'
   ELSE 'Tie'
   END) as result,
 layouts.name AS layout, date(end_time) AS date
FROM
 users_games
INNER JOIN
 users ON users_games.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN
 games ON users_games.game_id = games.id
INNER JOIN layouts
 ON games.layout_id = layouts.id 
 WHERE games.id IN (SELECT game_id FROM users_games WHERE user_id = 'some_user_id') 
 ORDER BY games.id asc;
```

I feel the way I have written it is very inefficient and difficult to read, but that's a different question..

The issue I'm facing is that I can't get a numbered index.

Here are the results of the above query:

```
 num | opponent_name | opponent_score | player_score | result | layout  |    date    
-----+---------------+----------------+--------------+--------+---------+------------
   1 | Medium AI     |             34 |            3 | Lost   | oldcity | 2021-08-31
   3 | Easy AI       |             21 |           31 | Won    | razeway | 2021-09-01
   5 | Easy AI       |             43 |           22 | Lost   | razeway | 2021-09-01
   7 | Easy AI       |             10 |           32 | Won    | razeway | 2021-09-01
   9 | Medium AI     |             10 |           32 | Won    | razeway | 2021-09-01
  11 | Medium AI     |             34 |           15 | Lost   | razeway | 2021-09-01
  13 | Medium AI     |             56 |           21 | Lost   | oldcity | 2021-09-01
  15 | Easy AI       |             22 |           22 | Tie    | razeway | 2021-09-03
```

As you can see the `num` column is skipping a digit on each column. That seems to be because my query is actually generating 2 rows, 1 for each user in each game, which I solve by using `DISTINCT ON (games.id)` in my query.

I have also tried to use `count(*)` to generate the `num` index, or using `group by games.id` or `group by game_id` but in each case I get the following error:

`ERROR:  subquery uses ungrouped column "games.id" from outer query`

How can I generate a numeric index, starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 for each row in the results from my query?

Comment: Get rid of the DISTINCT ON, then get your query to return the results you want without the numbering. Then wrap the whole thing in `SELECT row_number() over (), * from (...)_`. (The trailing underscore matters, PG requires subqueries in the FROM list to be named. In this case, we're calling it `_`).

Comment: This worked, thank you! If you add it as an answer rather than a comment I can mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `DISTINCT ON`, then get your query to return the results you want without the numbering. Then, wrap the whole thing in `SELECT row_number() over (), * from (...)_`. The trailing underscore does matter, Postgres requires subqueries in the `FROM` list to be named. In this case, we're calling it `_`.